# Can't filter mutated column

Tags: r, dplyr

Attempting to pull the lowest proportion of success between days.

I've filtered the data down to and mutated in the proportions of successes for each day:

```
structure(list(weekday = c("Friday", "Friday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Saturday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Thursday", "Thursday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday"), successful = c(FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), n = c(38404L, 19923L, 39467L, 21761L, 22023L, 
10694L, 13655L, 7393L, 39231L, 21365L, 48520L, 28787L, 43405L, 
24033L), proportion = c(65.8425771940954, 34.1574228059046, 64.4590710132619, 
35.5409289867381, 67.313629000214, 32.686370999786, 64.8755226149753, 
35.1244773850247, 64.7418971549277, 35.2581028450723, 62.7627511092139, 
37.2372488907861, 64.3628221477505, 35.6371778522495)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), groups = structure(list(
    weekday = c("Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Thursday", 
    "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), .rows = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 
        9:10, 11:12, 13:14)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Using:

```
mutate(weekday = weekdays(as.Date(launched)),
         successful = state == "successful") %>% 
  count(weekday, successful) %>% 
  group_by(weekday) %>% 
  mutate(proportion = n/sum(n) * 100)
```

on the original dataset.

Trying `%>% filter(proportion == (min(proportion, na.rm = T)))` just filters out the data in which 'successful' is false:

```
structure(list(weekday = c("Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), successful = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), n = c(19923L, 21761L, 10694L, 
7393L, 21365L, 28787L, 24033L), proportion = c(34.1574228059046, 
35.5409289867381, 32.686370999786, 35.1244773850247, 35.2581028450723, 
37.2372488907861, 35.6371778522495)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), groups = structure(list(
    weekday = c("Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Thursday", 
    "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
        6L, 7L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

The only function that has worked for me on the 'proportion' column was `%>% arrange(proportion)`, but using `%>% slice(proportion, 1)` right after gives the same result as above.

For clarification, filtering for the minimum proportion value gives me:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   weekday [7]
  weekday   successful     n proportion
  <chr>     <lgl>      <int>      <dbl>
1 Friday    TRUE       19923       34.2
2 Monday    TRUE       21761       35.5
3 Saturday  TRUE       10694       32.7
4 Sunday    TRUE        7393       35.1
5 Thursday  TRUE       21365       35.3
6 Tuesday   TRUE       28787       37.2
7 Wednesday TRUE       24033       35.6
```

Instead of:

```
  weekday   successful     n proportion
  <chr>     <lgl>      <int>      <dbl>
1 Sunday    TRUE        7393       35.1
```

Comment: Can you display the R output/error when you attempt your code?

Comment: Code executes without errors:


`> worst_launch_day <- ks_df %>% 
+   mutate(weekday = weekdays(as.Date(launched)),
+          successful = state == "successful") %>% 
+   count(weekday, successful) %>% 
+   group_by(weekday) %>% 
+   mutate(proportion = n/sum(n) * 100) %>% 
+   filter(proportion == (min(proportion, na.rm = T)))`

Comment: Expected output is just the column with the lowest 'proportion' value:

`Saturday  TRUE       10694       32.7`



Instead, I'm getting : `# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   weekday [7]
  weekday   successful     n proportion
  <chr>     <lgl>      <int>      <dbl>
1 Friday    TRUE       19923       34.2
2 Monday    TRUE       21761       35.5
3 Saturday  TRUE       10694       32.7
4 Sunday    TRUE        7393       35.1
5 Thursday  TRUE       21365       35.3
6 Tuesday   TRUE       28787       37.2
7 Wednesday TRUE       24033       35.6
`

Comment: `df %>% ungroup() %>% filter(proportion == min(proportion))`

Comment: For each weekday or overall? If you want it overall add `ungroup %>%
  slice(which.min(proportion))` or remove `ungroup` if you need for each `weekday`.

Comment: Thanks @andrew_reece! That did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone. Pretty new to R and dplyr, wasn't aware that I needed to ungroup first. Good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `ungroup()`, then your `filter` statement will work.

```
df %>% ungroup() %>% filter(proportion == min(proportion))
```